# Some text in my design disappears in PDF. InDesign Version 16.0

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

When I export my inDesign document as a PDF, some text randomly disappears (see orange text on the screenshots below).

[image: Screenshot from InDesign]

[image: Screenshot from PDF]

I tried converting text to outlines and that did not work.
Same colored text on other pages appear in my PDF.

Comment: Have you checked that the text frames aren’t set to not print? That would be the first thing I’d check.

Comment: Tried that - did nothing, unfortunately...

Comment: And they’re not on a separate layer that’s set to not print either?

Comment: Checked. No, same layer.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software are you using to view the PDF?  Try using Adobe Acrobat (or Reader).

Answer (score 0):

The text in question is marked as non-printing (Attributes panel, [x] Nonprinting). In the example below the second text box is marked as non-printing, therefore will not export.

[image]

If you don't want to hunt down all the objects that are marked as non-printing, check the
[x] Non-printing Objects in the PDF export dialog.

[image]

Comment: Given that the asker stated in a comment that the text frames are _not_ marked as non-printing, this doesn’t seem likely to be the correct reason.